# Android - Without Scan QRCode, need to get data from QRcode photo which is already saved in photo gallery

Tags: android, zxing, qr-code, email-attachments

I am using zxing library for scanning the Qr-code and its perfectly working.
But as my client new requirement about if we send update information through email with attached Qr-code image to the customer. How could we fetch the image and get the qr-code detail from the image using my app?

Or Do we decode QRCode Image??